# Error en la creación de Arrays

Tags: java

estoy haciendo una Array de Libros y Autores (anteriormente ya he formulado preguntas referidas a esa clase).

```
 public class Autor {

 private Libro[] librosEscritos;

    public Autor(String nombre, String email, Libro[] librosEscritos) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.email = email;
    this.librosEscritos = librosEscritos;
}


public class Libro {
private final String nombreLibro;
private final double precioLibro;
private final int cantidadEnStock;

public Libro(String nombreLibro, double precioLibro, int    cantidadEnStock) {
    this.nombreLibro = nombreLibro;
    this.precioLibro = precioLibro;
    this.cantidadEnStock = cantidadEnStock;

}
```

Estoy introduciendo estos libros y autores en el main y me sale este error.

```
     Autor[][] librosEscritos = new Autor[5][3];

    "carloszagon@hola.com", "dddd");

     Libro[][] librosEscritosPorAutor=new Libro [5][3];

     librosEscritosPorAutor[0]= new Libro ("La sombra del viento",9.2,);
```

[image: error]

Comment: Esta linea contiene un error, tu código no esta completo:   "carloszagon@hola.com", "dddd");

Comment: @Elenasys Contiene un error porque me pide un dato de tipo String, String, Libro [ ] de ahí la pregunta. no se que tipo de dato es Libro [ ] . Gracias!!

Comment: A quienes votan a cerrar la pregunta. La pregunta es clara, se entiende e inclusive tiene una respuesta. Sería bueno que por lo menos brinden un comentario como @Elenasys lo hizo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Es tan clara la pregunta que ni yo misma la veo. Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás intentando introducir un objeto `Libro` en un Array bidimensional. Deberías de introducir la "columna" de la matriz en la que quieres insertar el Libro:

```
librosEscritosPorAutor[0][0]= new Libro ("La sombra del viento",9.2,);
                          ↕
                         aquí
```

El `Array` bidimensional sería de tal manera:

```
[0,0] [0,1] [0,2] ...
[1,0] [1,1] [1,2] ...
[2,0] [2,1] [2,2] ...
... ... .... .... ...
```

Comment: Vale gracias, me ha desaparecido el error. ¿Pero si quiero almacenar libros, el siguiente seria [1] [1] y así sucesivamente?

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. El siguiente sería `[0][1]`